# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'CombinedExpression' and 'int'

Tags: django

I got this product model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    @property
    def value(self):
        return F('quantity') * F('price')
```

when I call .value on product instance I got in return:

```
product.value // returns 14
```

but when I check condition:

```
for product in Product.objects.all():
    while (product.value > 0):
        ...
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'CombinedExpression' and 'int'
```

**I have not found an existing question about this problem. How to solve it?**

Comment: `F('quantity') * F('price')` makes very little sense there!? Those are for use in queries. How did that supposedly return `14`? Just put `return self.quantity * self.price` there instead?

Comment: @deceze In my other question I was instructed to use F() in such situations. According to docs: "An F() object represents the value of a model field, transformed value of a model field, or annotated column. It makes it possible to refer to model field values and perform database operations using them without actually having to pull them out of the database into Python memory.". The second thing: the proposed solution doesn't change anything and still throws the same error.

Comment: @skelaw: no that is for *database expressions*, not for the Python/Django layer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It's good to know that it's not a correct use of F(), because I've been writing code this way for a long time, I won't be using it anymore even though the code worked before despite everything. It makes sense what you wrote. Thanks! However, I still get the error despite applying your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You work with the attributes directly:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # …

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.quantity * self.price
```

You use [**`F`**-expressions <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) to make expressions for *database queries*, not to multiply values at the Python/Django layer.

Comment: In my other question I was instructed to use F() in such situations. Before creating this question, I checked this... the proposed solution doesn't change anything and still throws the same error.